# Message appears twice using Skype SDK chat

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, skype, skype-for-business

i used skype sdk [Here](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk)   and here is my code snippet after

```
config.conversation.historyService.activityItems.added(function(newMsg) {
  if(typeof newMsg.direction != 'function') {} else {
    if(newMsg.direction() == 'Incoming') {
      direction = "black";
    } else if(newMsg.direction() == 'Outgoing' && newMsg.status() === "Succeeded") {
      direction = "green";
    } else {}
    $("#conversationText").append('<br/><div class="chat-user-info"><h1 class="chat-user-name">' + newMsg.sender.displayName() + '</h1><h2 class="chat-user-time">' + new Date() + '</h2></div><div class="chat-user-message"><h3 style="color:' + direction + ';">' + newMsg.text() + '</h3></div><br/>');
  }
});
```

But, the message appears when it is on state pending or even if fails , after this i try to put the message inside but it appears only on the other side not mine.

Github related issue [Here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/skype-web-sdk-samples/issues/11)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve this by workaround appending the message first regardless message.direction() value

Answer (score 1):

Why did you add the `typeof newMsg.direction != 'function'` condition, does it correct something ? 
The behaviour of your code seems correct here because the message appends only if the message is "Outgoing" and not "Succeeded".
Did you have any bugs or logs with the original solution wich is

```
conversation.historyService.activityItems.added(function(message) {
if (message.type() == 'TextMessage') {
    if (message.direction() == 'Incoming' ) {
        historyAppend(XMessage(message));
    } else if (message.direction() == 'Outgoing' && message.status() === "Succeeded") {
            historyAppend(XMessage(message));
    }
}
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying .... i wrote this condition coz it listen to the event twice one for baseModel object and one for Message object ... one of them throw exception if not handling it

Comment: Ok, I did not see that type of errors but I think they have changed the example a bit. 
Have you tried to print some logs with my solution ?
Try to print the status and the direction each time

Comment: sorry for lateness, i tested you code actually message status could be "pending" - "pending" then it "succeded" or "failed" where in both succeded or failed scenario it being send to the other side. So it couldn't be written on my side but delivered there.

Comment: Try to just print something in console inside the condition to see if it is not related to the display of the message. Have you checked the case too ?